# How to properly add texture to multi-fixture/shape b2Body

Tags: textures, box2d, cocos2d-iphone

Hello to everyone this is my first poste here I hope that will be not fail start.

At start I must say I make part 1 in Ray's Tutorial "How To Make A Game Like Fruit Ninja With Box2D and Cocos2D". But I wonder what when I want make more complex body with texture? Simple just add *n* b2FixtureDef to the same body.

OK but what about texture? If I will take code from that tutorial it only fill last fixture. Probably it does not takes every b2Vec2 point. I was right, it did not. So quick refactor and from that

```
-(id)initWithTexture:(CCTexture2D*)texture body:(b2Body*)body original:(BOOL)original
{
    // gather all the vertices from our Box2D shape
    b2Fixture *originalFixture = body->GetFixtureList();
    b2PolygonShape *shape = (b2PolygonShape*)originalFixture->GetShape();
    int vertexCount = shape->GetVertexCount();
    NSMutableArray *points = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:vertexCount];
    for(int i = 0; i < vertexCount; i++) {
        CGPoint p = ccp(shape->GetVertex(i).x * PTM_RATIO, shape->GetVertex(i).y * PTM_RATIO);
        [points addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:p]];
    }

    if ((self = [super initWithPoints:points andTexture:texture]))
    {
        _body = body;
        _body->SetUserData(self);
        _original = original;
        // gets the center of the polygon
        _centroid = self.body->GetLocalCenter();
        // assign an anchor point based on the center
        self.anchorPoint = ccp(_centroid.x * PTM_RATIO / texture.contentSize.width, 
                               _centroid.y * PTM_RATIO / texture.contentSize.height);
    }
    return self;
}
```

I came up with that

```
-(id)initWithTexture:(CCTexture2D*)texture body:(b2Body*)body original:(BOOL)original
{
    int vertexCount = 0;
    //gather total number of b2Vect2 points
    b2Fixture *currentFixture = body->GetFixtureList();
    while (currentFixture) { //new
        b2PolygonShape *shape = (b2PolygonShape*)currentFixture->GetShape();
        vertexCount += shape->GetVertexCount();
        currentFixture = currentFixture->GetNext();
    }


    NSMutableArray *points = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:vertexCount];
    // gather all the vertices from our Box2D shape
    b2Fixture *originalFixture = body->GetFixtureList();
    while (originalFixture) { //new
        NSLog((NSString*)@"-");
        b2PolygonShape *shape = (b2PolygonShape*)originalFixture->GetShape();
        int currentVertexCount = shape->GetVertexCount();

        for(int i = 0; i < currentVertexCount; i++) {
            CGPoint p = ccp(shape->GetVertex(i).x * PTM_RATIO, shape->GetVertex(i).y * PTM_RATIO);
            [points addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:p]];
        }
        originalFixture = originalFixture->GetNext();
    }

    if ((self = [super initWithPoints:points andTexture:texture]))
    {
        _body = body;
        _body->SetUserData(self);
        _original = original;
        // gets the center of the polygon
        _centroid = self.body->GetLocalCenter();
        // assign an anchor point based on the center
        self.anchorPoint = ccp(_centroid.x * PTM_RATIO / texture.contentSize.width,_centroid.y * PTM_RATIO / texture.contentSize.height);
    }
    return self;
}
```

I was working for simple two fixtures body like

```
b2BodyDef bodyDef;
bodyDef.type = b2_dynamicBody;
bodyDef.position = position;
bodyDef.angle = rotation;
b2Body *body = world->CreateBody(&bodyDef);

b2FixtureDef fixtureDef;
fixtureDef.density = 1.0;
fixtureDef.friction = 0.5;
fixtureDef.restitution = 0.2;
fixtureDef.filter.categoryBits = 0x0001;
fixtureDef.filter.maskBits = 0x0001;

b2Vec2 vertices[] = {
    b2Vec2(0.0/PTM_RATIO,50.0/PTM_RATIO),
    b2Vec2(0.0/PTM_RATIO,0.0/PTM_RATIO),
    b2Vec2(50.0/PTM_RATIO,30.1/PTM_RATIO),
    b2Vec2(60.0/PTM_RATIO,60.0/PTM_RATIO)
};

b2PolygonShape shape;
shape.Set(vertices, 4);
fixtureDef.shape = &shape;
body->CreateFixture(&fixtureDef);

b2Vec2 vertices2[] = {
    b2Vec2(20.0/PTM_RATIO,50.0/PTM_RATIO),
    b2Vec2(20.0/PTM_RATIO,0.0/PTM_RATIO),
    b2Vec2(70.0/PTM_RATIO,30.1/PTM_RATIO),
    b2Vec2(80.0/PTM_RATIO,60.0/PTM_RATIO)
};

shape.Set(vertices2, 4);
fixtureDef.shape = &shape;
body->CreateFixture(&fixtureDef);
```

But if I try put secondary shape upper than first it starting wierd, texture goes crazy. For [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bofPU.png) not mention about more complex shapes. What's more if shapes have one common point texture will not render for them at all [For that I use Physics Edytor like in tutorial part1]

BTW. I use PolygonSprite and in method createWithWorld... another shapes.

### **Uff.. Question**

So my question is, why texture coords are in such a mess up? It's my modify method or just wrong approach? Maybe I should remove duplicated from points array?

### **UPDATE**

Ok I did it, it's clearly bad texture coords. If some one want more specify anwser just let me know and I will post it.